# Django website stuck on default Nginx welcome page

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, web-hosting

So I tried hosting my client's website on Linode and I made the site using django. I am using Nginx and gunicorn for hosting but I am stuck in the default Nginx page. The following is my Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.ip.address scopeplus.org www.scopeplus.org;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/scope_website/scope;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

The following is my gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/scope_website
ExecStart=/root/venvPath/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          scope_website.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The following is my gunicorn.socket file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

My settings.py file is located at the following path:

```
root@localhost:~/scope_website/scope_website# pwd
/root/scope_website/scope_website
root@localhost:~/scope_website/scope_website# ls
asgi.py  __init__.py  __pycache__  settings.py  urls.py  wsgi.py
```

The following is the journalctl output from the Ubuntu terminal:

```
Jan 20 14:24:33 localhost gunicorn[7619]: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /
Jan 20 14:24:33 localhost gunicorn[7619]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:14:24:33 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 403 2869 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jan 20 14:45:50 localhost gunicorn[7617]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:14:45:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
Jan 20 14:46:09 localhost gunicorn[7617]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:14:46:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
Jan 20 15:03:38 localhost gunicorn[7618]: Not Found: /.env
Jan 20 15:03:38 localhost gunicorn[7618]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:03:38 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.0" 404 2810 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-US; HM NOTE 1W Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 UCBrowser/11.0.5.850 U3/0.8.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
Jan 20 15:03:38 localhost gunicorn[7619]: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /
Jan 20 15:03:38 localhost gunicorn[7619]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:03:38 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 403 2869 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-US; HM NOTE 1W Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 UCBrowser/11.0.5.850 U3/0.8.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
Jan 20 15:08:22 localhost gunicorn[7617]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:08:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
Jan 20 15:08:32 localhost gunicorn[7619]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:08:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
Jan 20 15:16:19 localhost gunicorn[7618]: Not Found: /.env
Jan 20 15:16:19 localhost gunicorn[7618]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:16:19 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.0" 404 2810 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jan 20 15:16:20 localhost gunicorn[7619]: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /
Jan 20 15:16:20 localhost gunicorn[7619]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:16:20 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 403 2869 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Jan 20 15:18:54 localhost gunicorn[7619]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:18:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
Jan 20 15:31:10 localhost gunicorn[7618]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:31:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.0.0"
Jan 20 15:31:30 localhost gunicorn[7618]: Not Found: /robots.txt
Jan 20 15:31:30 localhost gunicorn[7618]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:31:30 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 2828 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
Jan 20 15:31:31 localhost gunicorn[7618]: Not Found: /sitemap.xml
Jan 20 15:31:31 localhost gunicorn[7618]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:31:31 +0000] "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 2831 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
Jan 20 15:38:30 localhost gunicorn[7619]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:38:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
Jan 20 15:38:48 localhost gunicorn[7617]:  - - [20/Jan/2024:15:38:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I apologize for the overload of information, it's just that I'm new to web development so it's a new thing for me. I did a quick nslookup of my domain and it yielded to the right IP adress being printed in the terminal. How do I proceed from here?

Also, I have allowed traffic on port 80 and my Nginx error log is empty

Answer (score 0):

**1. Nginx config:**

- Make sure that root directive in your Nginx config is pointing to the correct location of your Django project's static files - common structure is `/path/to/your/django/project/static`, but it's depending on your project structure.
- After running `python manage.py collectstatic`, you should manually check `/root/scope_website/scope/static` directory in order to be sure that your static files are there.
- Sometimes, the default Nginx server block interferes, just check if there's a default file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` or `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and consider removing or modifying it.

**2. Gunicorn and Socket config:**

- Your socket file should be double checked, is your Gunicorn socket file generated at all (`/run/gunicorn.sock`)? Use `ls -l /run/gunicorn.sock` to see if the file exists and has the correct permissions.
- Look at Gunicorn's logs for any setup errors when you actually try to do serve request.

**3. Django config:**

- Temporarily enabling Django's debug mode by setting `DEBUG = True` in your `settings.py` to get detailed error messages, as it's insecure for a production environment
- You should do middleware check (for CSRF handling, ensure that it's all included in `settings.py`)
- Check that your Django app can connect to its database.

**Security Considerations:**
User Permissions: Running Gunicorn as root is not recommended for security reasons. Consider creating a new user for running your application.